# Display star rating on loop

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to figure out how I can output the star rating that is displayed on the product page into the loop. Here is the code that I have trying to output the star onto the loop

```
<div class="product-rating">
    <?php echo '<div class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $average).'"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>'; ?>
</div>
```

Right now the product only shows the text and doesn't output the correct rating. I have already given it a rating for testing and it only show "out of 5" Here is a screenshot of the post

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/product_zpsaf2b219a.jpg

```
<ul class="products eight columns">
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'Lumiere', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

            <li class="product product-items ">    

                <div class="product-item">

                    <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                    <div class="product-thumbnail">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" />'; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="product-info">
                    <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

                    <?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>
                    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>


                    <?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
                        <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>  


                    <div class="product-rating">
                    <?php echo '<div class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $average).'"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>'; ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

                    </div>

                </div>



            </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

Comment: Without knowing more about the surrounding code, my guess is that $average is not being set for your loop. Add this after the opening div tag: <?php var_dump($average); ?>

Comment: After adding the code you specified it is showing a "NULL" text. I also added the entire code for you to see

Comment: My guess is that there is a property of the $product object that you need to get to populate $average, similar to how you set $price_html = $product->get_price_html() a few lines earlier. If you var_dump($product), do you see a value in there for average rating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm right, the solution will look something like this:

```
<div class="product-rating">
    <?php if ($average = $product->get_average_rating()) : ?>
        <?php echo '<div class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $average).'"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution work. Thanks dude. Right now my only problem is trying to implement font awesome so that it shows stars rather than text

Comment: Can't help you there, but glad your PHP problem is fixed.